# how to check whether my cts:and-query or cts:or-query contains any element queries

Tags: xquery, marklogic, marklogic-9

I have a function which will return either `cts:and-query()` or `cts:or-query()`.

How can I validate whether the query is empty (without any element or collection queries inside it)?

I want to filter queries like below

```
cts:and-query(cts:or-query((), ()), ())
```

Answer (score 4):

The most reliable way to validate a whether a query is empty by your definition is to recursively walk the query until a non-empty query element is encountered, or if not, return true.

It's a little easier to do this by first converting the query to XML:

```
declare function local:is-empty-query(
  $q as schema-element(cts:query)*
)
{
  if (empty($q)) then true()
  else if (every $e in $q satisfies ($e/self::cts:and-query or $e/self::cts:or-query))
  then local:is-empty-query($q/*)
  else false()
};


local:is-empty-query(document { cts:and-query((cts:or-query((), ()))) }/*)
=> true()

local:is-empty(document { cts:and-query((cts:or-query((cts:word-query('test'), ())))) }/*)
=> false()
```

Comment: This code converts the query to xml for processing, but you can also walk through using native types, and typeswitch.

Comment: @grtjn could you please elaborate, perhaps in an answer of your own?

Comment: @FanLi `cts:` queries are their own types, which can be introspected via XQuery, just like the XML equivalents in my answer. So you could perform this same operation, recursively walking the original types (see: https://docs.marklogic.com/cts:and-query-queries). However, it's more verbose to do this, as each type (OR/AND) would need to be handled individually, while using XML you can do it in one step.